# Character encoding and VALARM with .ics files for Google Calendar -> iPhone

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am generating an iCal `.ics` file with Python that I publish to my FTP. I then add the URL to Google Calendar - the Python script uploads the file and (hopefully) Google will refresh it once every day or so and eventually I can add it to my iPhone calendar subscriptions through Google.

Google Calendar reads the file and displays my event, with a couple of problems:

- I am using some "foreign" characters (å, ä, ö) and in Google Calendar these show up as ��. I save the file as UTF-8, tried with and without BOM, I also added the following MIME content type type to my FTP provider: `text/calendar .ics`.
- Alerts (`VALARM` sections in the file) don't seem to be recognized by Google Calendar at all.

Appreciate any help on the topic. The `.ics` (slightly modified values) is included below. It validates to 100% using an online iCal validation site.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//My Name//My App Name//SV
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Sthlm
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20111030T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:SUMMER
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20120325T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:WINTER
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:somegeneratedid@myname.mydomain
DTSTART;TZID=Sthlm:20120320T165000
DTEND;TZID=Sthlm:20120320T170000
SUMMARY:Strange character å
DESCRIPTION:This is the description
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT60M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Alert alert
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: The foreign characters problem was solved by configuring my webserver with a content type "text/calendar; charset=UTF-8".

Comment: You can put this as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreign characters problem was solved by configuring my webserver with a content type "text/calendar; charset=UTF-8".

Answer (score 2):

For the VALARM not working, double check that the end-of-line being used is `\r\n`, not just `\n` as is incorrectly shown in many examples on the web.

For more detail see my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16540934/834431

Comment: `\n` seems to work, but mixing `\r\n`'s and `\n`'s will cause errors.

Comment: @Gerben see the linked question in my answer, although \n seems to work in many cases, it is incorrect and won't work reliably. You're right though, you shouldn't be mixing `\r\n` and `\n` - they should all be `\r\n` (Why you would be mixing them I'm not sure though?)

Comment: My editor used `\n` for line endings while the php script I wrote `\r\n`. But you are absolutely right; Don't tempt faith and just use `\r\n` :-)

Comment: Also, be sure that the last line ends with `\r\n`!